# How to make file .json with codeigniter?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, controller, jsonencoder

This is my json encode in my controller:

```
public function loaddata(){
    $sql = $this->db->query('select * from e_alat_angkutan')->result();

    return json_encode($sql);

}
```

how to make file .json ? please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write to JSON file using CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744488/write-to-json-file-using-codeigniter)

Comment: You mean headers or you want to write it to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller `__construct()` method load the file helper:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('file');
}
```

And then echo it with second param to TRUE:

```
public function loaddata(){
    $sql = $this->db->query('select * from e_alat_angkutan')->result();

    echo json_encode($sql,TRUE);
}
```

As points this answer [Write to JSON file using CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744488/write-to-json-file-using-codeigniter):

```
//If the json is correct, you can then write the file and load the view

// $fp = fopen('./data.json', 'w');
// fwrite($fp, json_encode($sql));

// if ( ! write_file('./data.json', $arr))
// {
//     echo 'Unable to write the file';
// }
// else
// {
//     echo 'file written';
// }
```

Hope it helps!